# Chrome: overflow:auto + margin:auto fails to layout correctly sometimes

Tags: css, google-chrome, webkit, css-float, overflow

I'm trying to layout a page which has anchor elements that I would like on a new line and centered. However these blocks are inside of `<p>` elements which are beside floating images.

**Right:**
http://test.sunnysidemarket.ca/right.jpg

**Wrong:**
http://test.sunnysidemarket.ca/wrong.jpg

So basically I have:

**HTML**:

```
<div class="content">
    <div>
        <img src="..." width="276" height="207" />
    </div>
    <div class="body">
          <p>
            ...
            <a class="mediaset" href="...">Link</a>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.content img {
    float: right;
}

a.mediaset {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 220px;
    display: block;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Or what you can see in the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CVkFw/

The issue is intermittent, sometimes it happens, sometimes it doesn't. What it appears to me to be is a bug in chrome where the overflow and margin properties are calculated but when the floating content loads, sometimes the browser doesn't layout the elements again.

**There are ways of solving this using jQuery and modifying my HTML but I would really love to solve this with CSS if at all possible.**

Comment: Short answer: don't use `<p>`. And what do you mean by "sometimes"?

Comment: The content is auto generated, so I would like to stay away from trying to edit it. By sometimes, I mean exactly that; it is intermittent.

Comment: When you load the page and it is laid out correctly, you can see it first being positioned incorrectly and then moving to the correct spot. Also, if it doesn't appear in the right spot and you change any properties in chrome-bug, it will promptly be corrected.

Comment: So does it do the same in other browsers?

Comment: No, seems to only be an issue with Chrome.

Comment: Odd. I'm not too sure why this happens. You can always submit a ticket here if there's nothing else you can do about it: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list

Comment: Just so you know, the same thing happened for me, intermittently, with Safari on the third link. Maybe an issue with Webkit?

Comment: @Godwin It displays fine for me (even in chrome). I checked all the pages that you put in the question, and all of them display well. Except link [2] which doesn't exist.

Comment: @Aniket I implemented wxactly's fix so you shouldn't get the issue on the site anymore, however you should be able to reproduce it in the jsfiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My best guess is that this erratic behavior is caused by `overflow: visible` applied in global.styles.css. The problem:

```
.node-article .field-name-body,
.node-synced-facebook-content .field-name-body {
    overflow: visible;
}
```

I'm offering this suggestion because when I add this CSS override for `overflow: hidden`, that component appears to load "more solidly". The fix:

```
.node-article .field-name-body,
.node-synced-facebook-content .field-name-body {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

The selector itself might need to be adjusted depending on what it is intended to affect. (I'm obviously not that familiar your page's css code.) Hopefully this points you in the right direction though!

Comment: This seems to have fixed it, although it's a difficult one to know for sure since it only occurs sometimes. Thanks!